# Do the dipole antenna edges have earth potential or is it a closed circuit made of co-axial cable?

Tags: voltage, current, antenna, earth, grounding

I understand the shape of the dipole antenna, but how is it fed so that the current only flows through one direction during the half cycle?
Even in a normal pole antenna, is there a ground at the edge of the antenna so that there is a potential difference?

Answer (score 0):

A1: It doesn't flow through one direction during the half cycle, it's AC.

"Normal pole antenna" - what kind is this antenna? Perhaps you meant quarter wavelength antenna?

A2: The current flows through air due to the capacitance, from one half to the another half of the antenna - for a dipole.

For a quarter length, the ground acts as the second part of the antenna, therefore the coax is grounded at the antenna. A dipole antenna has to use BALUN transformer if fed from coax.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand,is this correct:https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Dipole_antenna_standing_waves_animation_461x217x150ms.gif, if it is without a potential difference, why does current flow to the poles at all?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna

Comment: @user163416 It's like a capacitor. The potential difference is between each half of antenna.

Comment: oh, this was the answer I was searching for. Thanks. But if this is the case, shouldn't the charges be more cramped at the small gap rather than going near the edge/pole edges? And wouldn't that mean no creation of the em waves? And does that also mean the simple capacitor circuit leads to this radiation?

Comment: A balun is not essential with a coax transmission line.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič won't the charges get cramped at the ends? Why would it spread across the whole length of the antenna?